# form.$setPristine() não funciona + AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directives

Estou tentando fazer uma limpeza em um form, utilizado $setPristine() do angularJs...

Ao tentar limpar um fomulario com:

```
$scope.reset = function(){
   $scope.form.$setPristine();
      $scope.perfilDeAcesso = '';
};
```

funciona normalmente mas estou tentando criar uma diretiva,
e pra mesma funcionar preciso de um codigo parecido com esse:

```
$scope.limpar = function(modelForm,modelObjeto){
    console.log(modelForm);
    console.log(modelObjeto);
    modelObjeto = {};
    modelForm.$setPristine();
};
```

minha saida no console ao clicar duas vezes no botao que chama a function

```
c {$error: Object, $name: "formPerfilDeAcesso", $dirty: true, $pristine: false, $valid:    true…}
perfilDeAcessoCtrl.js:73
Object {itensPerfilDeAcesso: Array[3], nome: "ssssssssssssss"}
perfilDeAcessoCtrl.js:74
c {$error: Object, $name: "formPerfilDeAcesso", $dirty: false, $pristine: true, $valid:  true…}
perfilDeAcessoCtrl.js:73
Object {itensPerfilDeAcesso: Array[3], nome: "ssssssssssssss"}
```

neste trexo de codigo dá pra notar que o methdo $setPristine() funcionou pois o atributo $pristine foi alterado, porem o objeto não foi setado para vázio....

alguem sabe me dizer o porque?

Comment: Descobri oque era... quando eu passo um objeto que esta no meu scopo como parametro pra outro scope ou pro mesmo scope não tem como modificar o objeto, no caso eu resolvi implmentando uma diretiva.

Answer (score 1):

Descobri oque era... quando eu passo um objeto que esta no meu scopo como parametro pra outro scope ou pro mesmo scope não tem como modificar o objeto, no caso eu resolvi implmentando uma diretiva.

```
.directive('feResetform', function($compile, $http) {
   return {
   restrict: 'E',
   scope: {
     reOrigem: '=',
     reReset:  '=',
     reForm:    '='
   },
  template: 
    '<button ng-click="resetForm()" class="btn btn-warning" ng-if="!visualizar">'+
    ' Limpar  '+ 
    '</button>',
  replace: true,
  controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.resetForm = function(){       
      $scope.reReset = angular.copy($scope.reOrigem);
      $scope.reForm.$setPristine();  
   }
  }]
}
```

Minha tag passando os parametros..

```
 <fe-resetform re-origem="objetoOrigem" re-reset="perfilDeAcesso" re-  form="formPerfilDeAcesso"></fe-resetform>
```